# Limit of x cos(x^-2) at x=0

Tags: limits

How to show that the following is true?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried expanding cosine as a series?

Comment: As in replace cosine with some other terms? I don't think I am capable of that.

Comment: try squeeze theorem

Comment: So $1/x^2$ grows without bound. What do you know about cosines of very large angles? Very little actually, but that is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $-1\le\cos t\le 1$ for any real number $t$, then $$-|x|\le x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\le |x|,\qquad x\neq 0$$ And now use the Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: Does this implies that the limit is the same approached from either side?

Comment: @user289661: Yes, it does. The function is boundend by $-|x|$ and $|x|$. Then as $x$ tends to $0$ the function goes to $0$.